# How to count the number of swaps that occur in a merge sort - Java

Tags: java, mergesort

I have been working on developing a merge sort algorithm. One of the things I need to figure out is how many swaps are occurring during the algorithm. My code is as follows:

```java
    int[] MergeSort(int[] sortArray, int size) {
        //Base case
        if (size < 2) {
            return sortArray;
        }

        //Finding the middle of the input array and splitting it into two new arrays based on that middle value
        int middle = size / 2;
        int[] leftArray = new int[middle];
        int[] rightArray = new int[size - middle];

        //Copy data from the input array to the new arrays
        for (int i = 0; i < middle; i++) {
            leftArray[i] = sortArray[i];
        }
        for (int j = middle; j < size; j++) {
            rightArray[j - middle] = sortArray[j];
        }

        //Recursively call the mergesort until the size of the array on each side is one
        MergeSort(leftArray, middle);
        MergeSort(rightArray, size - middle);

        //Stack will recursively merge all of the arrays back together in numerical order
        merge(sortArray, leftArray, rightArray, middle, size - middle);

        //Return the sorted array (the last return will be what the test class gets)
        return sortArray;
    }

    private void merge(int[] sortArray, int[] leftArray, int[] rightArray, int left, int right) {
        //These will be our loop counters that will indicate if we are getting close to the end of the arrays
        //(the ends being given by left and right)
        int leftCounter = 0;
        int rightCounter = 0;
        int sortCounter = 0;

        //
        while (leftCounter < left && rightCounter < right) {
            if (leftArray[leftCounter] <= rightArray[rightCounter]) {
                sortArray[sortCounter++] = leftArray[leftCounter++];

            } else {
                sortArray[sortCounter++] = rightArray[rightCounter++];
                System.out.println("flag");
            }
            comparisons++;


        }
        while (leftCounter < left) {
            sortArray[sortCounter++] = leftArray[leftCounter++];

        }
        while (rightCounter < right) {
            sortArray[sortCounter++] = rightArray[rightCounter++];

        }
    }
```

The problem I am running into is that for some reason the else branch containing the `System.out.println("flag")` line is never being run. Every example I have seen of counting the swaps in a merge sort has incremented the swaps in that branch.

All of that said, the algorithm works - if I give it an array it will sort the array properly (these are arrays containing randomly generated numbers). It simply is not accessing that branch so I do not know where to increment the swaps. The best assistance I could receive would be information on where and how I need to increment the swaps.

Comment: Have you tried inputting deliberately contrived data, which will traverse the path you expect? For example, without testing it, I think giving it an array of `[1, 0]` should end up in the `else` clause in question. I'd do that, and follow through what happens, either in a debugger or adding more logging statements, and see what you learn.

Comment: I don't understand how it would be possible for that branch to never execute and the merge sort to work. It has to do swaps sometimes or it won't sort.

Comment: Additionally, and I'm not sure if it will be the cause of your problem here or not, but note that in the lines under your comment "Recursively call the mergesort..." you are ignoring the returned `int[]`s. I suspect that won't help with getting the correct results.

Comment: And, a final point, note that by convention Java methods start with a lower-case characters, so `MergeSort` should be `mergeSort`.

Comment: For the record, the sorting code works just fine. In fact, I'm getting "flag" in my output around 200 times for a random array of 100 ints. OP, can you provide sample data?

Comment: @LayneBernardo You ended up hitting the nail on the head. The fact that your code ran correctly surprised me so I went back and checked my input arrays. It turns out that I was passing the function pointers to arrays that had already been muted by previous sorting algorithms, which is why there were no swaps occurring. There was nothing to sort! Thanks so much for the help and the point in the right direction!

Comment: Glad to be of help!